# RIA services: Load returning no data

Tags: silverlight, binding, service, ria

In the BookClub example application from nikhilk Kothary, a combobox is used to display book categories.

It is like this in the viewmodel class (the application is using the MVVM pattern):

private ReferenceDataContext _referenceData;

public BookClubModel() { // Constructor
    _referenceData = new ReferenceDataContext();

```
_referenceData.Load(_referenceData.GetcategoriesQuery(), false);
```

}

Then there is a property to which the comboxbox is bound:

public IEnumerable Categories {
    get {
        return _referenceData.Categories;
    }
}

Why is this working? Shouldn't we have a "completed" event handler for the load operation?

If I want to fill a IEnumerable property in the constructor, then it is not working:

private ReferenceDataContext _referenceData;

private IEnumerable _categories;

public BookClubModel() { // Constructor
    _referenceData = new ReferenceDataContext();

```
_referenceData.Load(_referenceData.GetcategoriesQuery(), false);

_categories = _referenceData.Categories; _referenceData.Categories was what we were returning in the Categories property above.
```

}

Why does it work in one case and not for the other?

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

In first case `Categories` is reference to `_referenceData.Categories`. And when `_referenceData.Categories` collection was updated, `Categories` also updated.

In second case you need event handler for `Load` operation, then do what you want with loaded entities.

Internally when you call Load, query to database is performing and when result is fetched then called load operation callback. Load operation is async operation and you need to keep in mind that fact

Comment: But how does it work internaly? _referenceData.Categories is getting the list of categories from the context and as soon as it is loaded the property is updated? Does this mean that we don't have to make async loads always?

Comment: internally when you call Load, query to database is performing and when result is fetched then called load operation callback. load operation is async operation and you need to keep in mind that fact

Comment: An other question though. The load operation with a delegate I understand, but for the case of the "Categories" property, how does it works? First I load the query in the constructor, but I don't have any delegate. How can it gets the data when I'm using "return -referenceData.Categories" later on? Why when I write "_categories = _referenceData.Categories" _categories is not updated when the collection is updated? It is a reference to _reference.Categories too.

Comment: If returns just reference to _referenceData.Categories, not value. And this reference is updated internally by context when load operation is completed.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now :-) Thank you very much for your patience!